# CodeIgniter - método anti refresco

Tags: codeigniter

Llevo bastantes días atascado con un problema de un login que no tengo muy claro como atacar. Lo que quiero hacer es un login que al hacer 3 intentos te salte el típico mensaje de error 'Debe esperar 5 minutos para volver a intentarlo'. Así lo tengo planteado

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('parser');

    //Propios
    $this->load->helper('ver_ip');
    $this->load->helper('encriptar');
    // $this->load->helper('diferencia_tiempo');
    $this->load->model('M_login');
    $this->load->model('M_conexiones');
}

public function index()
{
    $data = array(
        'title_seo' => 'Login',
        'css'       => base_url('public/css/login.css?'.time()),
    );

    // $this->session->sess_destroy();

    //Intentas hacer login
    if($this->input->post()){
        $pass           = $this->security->xss_clean(strip_tags($this->input->post('pass')));
        $pass_encr      = encriptar($pass);
        $login_correcto = $this->M_login->existe_password($pass_encr);

        //vas a la web
        if($login_correcto){
            $this->session->set_userdata('logueado', TRUE);

            redirect('web');
        } 
        //Has fallado el login
        else{
            if($this->session->has_userdata('intento')){
                $intento = $this->session->intento +1;
                $this->session->set_userdata('intento', $intento);

                echo 'IF - Intento: '.$this->session->userdata('intento').'<br>';
            } else{
                $this->session->set_userdata('intento', 1);
                echo 'ELSE - Intento: '.$this->session->userdata('intento').'<br>';
            }
            $this->parser->parse('v_login', $data);
        }

    }
    //Cargas por primera vez
    else{
        //Creas un token -> guardar en una variable de sesion

        $this->parser->parse('v_login', $data);
    }
}
```

}

El problema viene cuando presiono F5 después de haber fallado el login. Me incrementa en uno los intentos y no quiero que eso suceda. He probado a intenta hacerlo con tokens, pero no tengo demasiado claro como funcionan.

Comment: Lo estas realizando como si reenviaras el formulario, deberias de mostrar un poco mas como tienes tu formulario para poder darte una mejor respuesta. Yo actualmente manejo alertas con tiempos y trabajo con tareas cron para quitar el bloqueo. Tambien es sencillo hacerlo por medio de un parámetro en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear una tabla en la db con **user_id**, **intentos** y **fecha_ultimo_intento**.
Cada vez que falle el login, se aumenta 1 intento y se graba la fecha y hora.
Al llegar a 3 intentos, se te muestra el mensaje de espera.

En el siguiente intento, si han pasado +5 minutos se empieza desde 1.

En el momento que se haga un login correcto, dejas los intentos a "0" y la fecha vacía.